# How can i add image names into an array?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

In my app, i have a little problem in memory issue.
My coding skill is not enough to perfect.
My code use memory four time that i really need.
How can i change my coding?

My Code is

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{ 
UIScrollView * ScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-88)];// 44(UpperNavigtionBar),-88(Upper+Lower)
ScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

// Create a UIImage to hold Info.png
UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image-001.jpg"];
UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image-002.jpg"];
UIImage *image3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image-003.jpg"];
UIImage *image4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image-004.jpg"];
UIImage *image5 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image-005.jpg"];
UIImage *image6 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image-006.jpg"];
UIImage *image7 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image-007.jpg"];
UIImage *image8 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image-008.jpg"];
UIImage *image9 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image-009.jpg"];
UIImage *image10 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image-010.jpg"];
UIImage *image11 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image-011.jpg"];
UIImage *image12 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image-012.jpg"];
UIImage *image13 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image-013.jpg"];

NSArray *images = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:image1,image2,image3,image4,image5,image6,image7,image8,image9,image10,image11,image12,image13,nil];


NSInteger numberOfViews = 13;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++)
{
    CGFloat xOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width;

    UIImageView * ImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-88)]; // -88(Upper+Lower)
    [ImageView setImage:[images objectAtIndex:i]];

    [ScrollView addSubview:ImageView];
}    
ScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width*numberOfViews, self.view.frame.size.height-88); // -88(for adding Image View as subview)
[self.view addSubview:ScrollView];
}
```

Comment: How did you determine that your code uses exactly four times the memory it would need?

Comment: @H2CO3, Firstly, i make 13 Image Objects. Second, add this objects into array. Third, add images into image view. Fourth, add image view into scroll view. That is my thinking H2CO3. How can i change my code?

Comment: sorry if that sounds harsh but I think you should 'freshen up' your basic knowledge. The objects are normally passed by reference and only the pointers to it by value so your number makes no sense at all. (that goes for many languages)

Comment: the code looks ok if you need 13 views.. but you likely dont :) maybe reduce it by lazy loading the imageviews when they are needed => when they are actually scrolled too... that would mean instead of 13 views, you'd likely only need 1-3 or so

Comment: @Daij-Djan, thanks for your reply. But, 13 is only for one view controller. Some, view controller use around 200 images in my story board. My app has around 600 images. My memory is full when opened around 150 images. Can i do anything?

Comment: Yes, as I said in my 2nd comment. lazy load the stuff and only ever add the 1-5 views you need at any ONE point in time look at the Apple PictureViewer code maybe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things you can do to limit your memory usage. First, you should fill your array with the names of the images, not the images themselves. Given the way your images are named, you should be able to do this in a loop. Second, when you load the image, use imageWithContentsOfFile: instead of imageNamed:. The latter method caches images, while the former doesn't. If you use imageNamed: the memory usage will continue to grow as you scroll through images (even with lazy loading) because of the caching -- at some point the system should purge the cache, which should keep your app from crashing, but I don't think it will keep the system for shutting down other programs that are in the background on a device.

Comment: sorry for my reply, thanks for your help. Now, i use first way as you say. I store image names into array. Now, my app can run with memory management. Thanks you so much.